# turns off wi-fi on the laptop

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

Wi-fi turns off when I try to move the laptop or in some moments just like that. during diagnostics, there is simply a "Reset of the adapter "Wireless network" " and the connection is restored again. I tried reinstalling the driver, it didn't help.

There is also often a blue screen with errors such as - DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION and some other driver-related errors

Just in case, laptop - ASUS TUF Gaming F17 FX706HM-HX082

How can this issue be resolved? or just reinstalling

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: Might also be related to security setup. Some laptops have an anti-theft feature using WiFi to post the machines location. Check for a BIOS setting. Also, try using *Airplane mode* to turn off *all* adapters (Bluetooth, too).

Comment: If a problem happens when you move something, there could be a loose part somewhere. In this case, it could be that the Wi-Fi card needs to be re-seated. A search for "ASUS TUF Gaming F17 wifi card" will lead to suitable instruction videos. N.B. the aerial connections are quite delicate and fiddly.

Comment: I had the exact same problem with my Asus laptop about an year ago — It turned out connections to the WiFi card were loose.